# Listen to this riddle carefully!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

Hi all! 
Here's a riddle. Please guess what thing is described below, and don't forget to explain each clue. :)

**- - - Riddle starts - - -**

Oh, my dear friend,
If you want to know who I am,
listen to me carefully,
and you shall understand

For I am a friend of many
in their times of uncertainty

In me
You shall find a love story
A tale of romance and tragedy

In me,
following the rhythm,
people swing their body

My eye
is a beautiful land of the East
A land of colors and spices

In my age,
People from far away
may find comfort and rest 

And if I look at you, my friend
Oh! You are not so different from the others

And now
Answer this, you may try:
Who am I?

**Hint 1:**

> As you may have guessed, I am a collection of things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be

> [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), which assigns to each letter and digit a word (i.e. a collection).

Because:

Oh, my dear friend,
If you want to know who I am,
listen to me carefully,
and you shall understand

> In case of a word being poorly understandable (e.g. in radio communication), one can spell it using the NATO alphabet.

For I am a friend of many
in their times of uncertainty

> The same - if you're uncertain about a word, you may ask to spell it.

In me
You shall find a love story
A tale of romance and tragedy

> Romeo (R) and Juliet (J).

In me,
following the rhythm,
people swing their body

> Foxtrot (F) is a dance

My eye
is a beautiful land of the East
A land of colors and spices

> India (I, i.e. "eye") is a land "of colors and spices".

In my age,
People from far away
may find comfort and rest

> Hotel (H, i.e. "age") is a place to rest.

And if I look at you, my friend
Oh! You are not so different from the others

> Uniform (U, i.e. "you") makes people look similarly.

Comment: I think you left out a T in one of your answers